# ROR + Error while installing Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In my system, I am trying to install `Rails 4 with Ruby2`. Ruby 2 is installed successfully. While installing Rails4, I made the configuration as per DevKit. Even though I am get the error message.

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>
> ERROR:  Error installing rails:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> ```
>
> *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

I am not getting the way to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the mkmf.log file for more details.

Comment: ... and paste it there.

Comment: which OS you are using?